# Is it possible to measure HTTP response latencies without changing my server code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a small number of HTTP servers on GCP VMs. I have a mixture of different server languages and Linux based OS's.

**Questions**

A. It it possible to use the Stackdriver monitoring service to set alerts at specific percentiles for HTTP response latencies?

B. Can I do this without editing the code of each server process?

C. Will installing the agent into the VM report HTTP latencies?

For example, if the 95th percentile goes over 100ms for a certain time period I want to know.

I know I can do this for CPU utilisation and other hypervisor provided stats using:

https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Request latencies are extracted by cloud load balancers. As long as you are using cloud load balancer you don't need to install monitoring agent to create alerts based 95th Percentile Metrics.

Monitoring agent captures latencies for some preconfigured systems such as riak, cassandra and some others. Here's a full list of systems and metrics monitoring agent supports by default: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent

But if you want anything custom, i.e. you want to measure request latencies from VM you would need to capture response times yourself and configure logging agent to create a custom metric which you can use to create alerts. And as long as you are capturing them as distribution metrics you should be able to visualise different percentiles (i.e. 25, 50, 75, 80, 90, 95 and 99th etc.) and create alert based on that.

see: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics

[image: Creating Distribution metrics]

Answer (score 1):

> A. It it possible to use the Stackdriver monitoring service to set
>   alerts at specific percentiles for HTTP response latencies?

If you want to simply consider network traffic, yes it is possible. Also if you are using a load balancer it's also possible to set alerts on that. 
What you want to do should be pretty straight forward from the interface, however you can also find more info in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/).

If you want to use some advanced metric on top of tomcat/apache2 etc, you should check the list of metrics provided by the stackdriver monitoring agent [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-apache).

> B. Can I do this without editing the code of each server process?

Yes, no need to update any program, stackdriver monitoring works transparently and will be able to fetch basic metrics from a GCP VMs without the need of the monitoring agent, including network traffic and cpu utilization.

> C. Will installing the agent into the VM report HTTP latencies?

No, the agent shouldn't cause any http latencies.

Comment: I am looking to graph the time duration of an HTTP request. (I am not looking for general network traffic stats into/out of the VM). I do not think I can do this without changing my app code. You misunderstand C; I am asking if the stack driver agent installed in a VM can report duration of HTTP requests for unmodified server processes.

Comment: Could you clarify when you mean time duration? Do you mean the length of time from when the request comes into the server , until the response leaves the server? Stackdriver Monitoring on GCE is based on the open source statistic collection daemon, collectd (https://collectd.org/). You can explore its capabilities by looking at its source code : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/#get-source-code

Comment: Yes by duration/latency I mean the length of time from when the request reaches the server to the time it is completed.

Comment: After doing some research I believe that the feature you are looking for is unavailable at this time. I would encourage you to open a new issue tracker and create a feature request. Describe in detail what your exact use case is for best results.